# Is it possible to merge video files with FFmpeg interlaced not concatenated?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video file that has the frames from 2 source mp4 video files interlaced like this:

```
I1 I2 P1 P2 I1 I2 P1 P2 I1 I2 P1 P2 ...
```

where `I = Intra`, `P = predicted`, and the numbers are from which source file they come.

Is this possible with FFmpeg commands? If not, if I use the `ffplay` code from `read_thread`, how do I put the content returned from `av_read_frame` into a proper video file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without transcoding. Here is a simple example for videos with same resolution and framerate:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='ifnot(mod(N,2),A,B)'[out]" -map [out] out.mp4
```

Check [this page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend_002c-tblend) for detail.

**Update**:

As Gyan's comment said, the command above will drop half the frames. So double the fps before interleave maybe better if you do not want to lost any information. Asume the input videos are constant 30 fps:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]framerate=60[in0];[1:v]framerate=60[in1];[in0][in1]blend=all_expr='ifnot(mod(N,2),A,B)'[out]" -map [out] out.mp4
```

Comment: This will lose half the frames for each input.

Comment: Thanks. This kinda works, but due to bidirectional predicted frames, parts of the second merge into the first. I really need totally separate video streams so that they can be extracted and played separately. Working with a muxer directly?